# XSLT 2.0 error handling: throw exception to javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I have an input XML File:

```
<Items>
    <Item Name="1" Value="Value1"></Item>
    <Item Name="2" Value="Value2"></Item>
</Items>
```

What I want to transform to following output file with Saxon-CE.

```
<Items>
    <Item Name="1" Value="NewValue1"></Item>
    <Item Name="2" Value="NewValue2"></Item>
</Items>
```

JS:

```
function TransformXML() {
    xsltData = Saxon.requestXML("transformXML.xsl");
    xmlData = Saxon.requestXML("myxml.xml");
    var xsltProcessor = Saxon.newXSLT20Processor(xsltData);
    var result = xsltProcessor.transformToDocument(xmlData);
    }
```

I have a mapping, that tells me the value of an item and the NewValue it should have after the transformation.
What I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">                    

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" name="xml" />

    <xsl:variable name="Items">
        <Item Name="1">
            <Value OldValue="Value1" NewValue="NewValue1" ></Value>
        </Item>
        <Item Name="2">
            <Value OldValue="Value2" NewValue="NewValue2" ></Value>
        </Item>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="Items">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>   

    <xsl:template match="Item">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:if test="not($Items/Item[@Name=current()/@Name]/Value[@OldValue = current()/@Value])">
                <!-- if value mismatch throw exception and stop -->
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:attribute name="Value">                    
                <xsl:value-of select="$Items/Item[@Name=current()/@Name]/Value[@OldValue = current()/@Value]/@NewValue"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*[name()!= 'Value']" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is working, but what I want to do now is to check if there is a value mismatch. 
If yes then the script should stop and throw an exception what I can catch in the Javascript function.
Is there a way to realize this? Can I set a callback function for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With XSLT, you can terminate processing using `<xsl:message select="'some message'" terminate="yes"/>`. It would be desirable that the `transformToDocument` method throws a Javascript exception you could catch with `try/catch` but it does not seem to happen, at least not in a quick test I did. I was however able to set an error handler and handle that message in that handler, see http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/xslt/test2014120301.html for an example, which does

```
function onSaxonLoad()
{
  Saxon.setLogLevel('SEVERE');
  var errors = [];
  Saxon.setErrorHandler(function(error) { errors.push(error); });

  var xslt = Saxon.requestXML("test2014120301.xsl")
  var xsltProc = Saxon.newXSLT20Processor(xslt);

  xsltProc.setInitialTemplate("main");

  var errorCount = errors.length;
  var doc = xsltProc.transformToDocument();
  if (errorCount < errors.length) {
    var msg = errors[errors.length - 1].message;
    var pre = document.createElement('pre');
    pre.textContent = msg;
    document.body.appendChild(pre);
  }
  else {
    // use result document doc here
  }      

}
```

The message Saxon pushes to the error handler is `SEVERE: XPathException in invokeTransform: Processing terminated by xsl:message in test2014120301.xsl`. Obviously there could be other errors pushed to the error handler so you will need more checks on the Javascript side to perhaps check that the message test contains `Processing terminated by xsl:message`.